# Adding business conditions based on foreign keys with default values

Tags: mysql, schema

I'm trying to create a normalized database schema with a very highly configurable system. Here's the challenge:

Our clients are constantly receiving jobs, each having values for a few foreign keys to various other parts of the system. We want to allow our clients to customize a number of configuration options based on where those foreign keys point. In general, this would be pretty easy, but we also want to let them specify default configurations (i.e. if they don't care where FK1 points). So for example, our jobs table looks something like this:

```
Jobs
{
   ID,
   ConfirmationNumber,
   Company_ID,
   FK1,
   FK2,
   FK3,
   FK4,
   Cost,
   Price,
   Total,
   DateCompleted
}
```

We want to allow them to specify configurations based on FK1-4, but with optional defaults. As of right now, we've created a configuration table with FK's 1-4, and all of the configuration options. We allow any FK to be NULL to specify that they don't care about that FK (i.e. defaults to any value), so here's what our table looks like:

```
Configs
{
   ID,
   Company_ID,
   FK1 (allow NULL),
   FK2 (allow NULL),
   FK3 (allow NULL),
   FK4 (allow NULL),
   Config1,
   Config2,
   ConfigN
}
```

My knowledge of the normal forms is below average, so I'm not sure which one this violates, but I'm sure it violates one of them. To me it seems like 2NF is violated, because sometimes the Config1-N will only depend on a subset of the FKs. The entire set of FKs + Company_ID make the candidate key, because each company should only have one unique configuration per set. However, by allowing NULL, the unique index will still allow many duplicate rows with any of the FK's NULLed out. Is there a better solution? The most "normal" to me would seem to be a table for every permutation of the FKs and corresponding configurations, but that's not really practical with the amount of foreign keys we have.

Comment: FK1-FK4 does not look normalized to me. Repeating columns like that is bad design. Rather break it into another table.

Comment: They aren't referring to the same table. One would be Account_ID, Customer_ID, Location_ID, etc.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment then.

Comment: After somewhat 25 years of designing databases, small like astronomical, on mostly all popular RDBMS, I have learned something for sure: I don't care about those strict normalization theories. My instinct is enough. As long as your database design and the code  that manipulates it are OK, you don't need to bother with those, even more, there are a lot of scenarios in which normalization is a very BAD thing, especially on large databases. To read [Maybe Normalizing Isn't Normal](https://blog.codinghorror.com/maybe-normalizing-isnt-normal/) Written 13 years ago and always true.